# How to increase fastcgi_read_timeout in google-app-engine nginx?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-php

I looking for a way to incease 'fastcgi_read_timeout' in GAE Flex using runtime_config 'nginx_conf_include'.

The reason to increase the timeout is my http request requires around 90seconds but the default only 60seconds.

Can't manage to find in SO and Google.

Answer (score 1):

You can create [nginx-app.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/runtime#customizing_nginx) file in the root directory of your service and add there a [fastcgi_read_timeout](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_read_timeout) directive:

```
location /* {
    fastcgi_send_timeout 60s;
}
```